# Как скрывать расширения .html и .php и редиректить на url без них на nginx?

Tags: php, nginx, php-nginx

Как скрывать расширения .html и .php и редиректить на url без них п помощью nginx?

То есть при переходе на `api.example.com/method/servers.get.php?ids=[2]` нужно перенапрявлять на `api.example.com/method/servers.get?ids=[2]`.

Есть уже готовый конфиг:

```
    server_name api.example.com  ;
    listen *.*.*.*:80;
    listen [*.*.*.*.*]:80;
    listen *.*.*.*:443 ssl ;
    listen [*.*.*.*.*]:443 ssl ;
    
    ssl_certificate "/var/www/httpd-cert/api.example.com_*-*-*-*-*_*.crt";
    ssl_certificate_key "/var/www/httpd-cert/api.example.com_*-*-*-*-*_*.key";
    
    charset utf-8;
    
    gzip on;
    gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_types text/css text/xml application/javascript text/plain application/json image/svg+xml image/x-icon;
    gzip_comp_level 1;
    
    set $root_path /var/www/*/data/www/api.example.com;
    root $root_path;
    disable_symlinks if_not_owner from=$root_path;
    
    rewrite index.php https://example.com last;
    rewrite ^/method/(.+)$ /public/$1 last;
    
    rewrite ^/public/(.+)$ https://api.example.com/method/$1 last;
    
    location ~* ^/(vendor)($|\/) {
        deny all;
    }
    
    location / {
        index index.php index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
    
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/api.bebra.host.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
    }
    
    
    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|js|css|mp3|ogg|mpeg|avi|zip|gz|bz2|rar|swf|ico|7z|doc|docx|map|ogg|otf|pdf|tff|tif|txt|wav|webp|woff|woff2|xls|xlsx|xml)$ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
    
    location @fallback {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/api.example.com.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
    
    include "/etc/nginx/fastpanel2-sites/*/api.example.com.includes";
    include /etc/nginx/fastpanel2-includes/*.conf;
    
    
    error_log /var/www/*/data/logs/api.example.com-frontend.error.log;
    access_log /var/www/*/data/logs/api.example.com-frontend.access.log;
}
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить его.

Comment: Обязательно нужно с помощью nginx? Если это ваш сервер, то проще сделать в файлике .htaccess

Comment: @DrMcSheen а давно nginx умеет читать .htaccess?

Comment: quss, так у вас файл servers.get.php существует или нет?

Comment: @DrMcSheen Да, обязательно.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Да, существует.

Answer (score 2):

Для 301 редиректа с отбрасыванием .html и .php добавьте в конфиг перед `location ~ \.php$`:

```
location ~ ^(.*)\.(?:html|php)$ {
    return 301 $1$is_args$args;
}
```

Но обращаю ваше внимание, что при этом `location ~ \.php$` уже не будет отрабатывать.

Comment: Редирект сработал только для /index.php и /index.html.
Для /indexx.php и /public/test.test.php редирект не происходит.
При переходе на /indexx и /public/test.test вручную отображается контент /index.

Comment: Но... Описанное ранее происходит если поставить ваш код ниже `location ~ \.php$`.
Если разместить его выше, то происходит цикличный 301 редирект.

Comment: И также даже для /index при добавлении get параметров редирект не происходит.

Comment: выбор location осуществляется в определенном приоритете. Об этом читайте по ссылке http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location Переставляя предложенный мной location над или под location ~ \.php вы меняете порядок обработки. Это происходит потому что если URL подходит под несколько location, то выбирается первое попавшееся

Comment: location матчит URL без параметров, поэтому они не мешают

Comment: Я не могу понять, что я делаю неправильно. Вроде бы всё должно работать, но оно не работает. Можно ли перейти в личные сообщения, чтобы решить проблему?

Comment: контакты в профиле